# What’s esperanto word for “aloft”

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m not native English speaker and there no corresponding word in Chinese so I don’t have idea how to build a logic and best-for word in Esperanto.

Comment: The word "aloft" means different things in different contexts. Please clarify what it is that you're trying to say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this would depend a lot on the context of where the word is being used. [John Well’s dictionary](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) has the following:

> **aloft** supr-e, -en

However, I think that only makes sense if the word is being used in the general sense of being in a place up high. If I think of something being *aloft* I generally think of it floating in the sky like a hot-air balloon. In that case *ŝvebanta* or *fluganta* might be approriate translations.

> **ŝvebi** (ntr) 1 ♉ Resti kvazaŭ pendanta en la aero, kun etenditaj, ne moviĝantaj flugiloj